# Adding an input tag dynamically in React, shows for a moment then disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What am trying to do is to be able to add an input field dynamically.
So for example, once you fill your first hobby, then you decide to add another one. you click on add and a new input field is shown.
The input field is showing for split second then disappearing.

Code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Hobbies: []
  }

  addHobby = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ Hobbies: [...prevState.Hobbies, ''] }))

  }

  handleChange(i, event) {
    let Hobbies = [...this.state.Hobbies];
    Hobbies[i] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ Hobbies });
  }

  removeClick(i) {
    let Hobbies = [...this.state.Hobbies];
    Hobbies.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ Hobbies });
  }

  render() {
    const widthStyle = {
      width: '15rem'
    };



    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form >
          <label>
            Hobbies:
          <input type="text" name="hobby" />
          </label>
          <br /><br />

          {
            
            this.state.Hobbies.map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={i}>
                  <input type="text" value={el || ''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
                  <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)} />
                </div>
              )
            })
          }

          <button onClick={this.addHobby.bind(this)}>ADD Hobby</button>
        </form>

       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are clicking inside a form which is why your page is getting refreshed(form submits) and you lose the state

```
addHobby = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault() //<-----
  this.setState({ Hobbies: [...this.state.Hobbies, ''] })
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3qwrojyw9)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the same problem still applies. The input field shows for a moment up then disappearsagain

Comment: you are a savior. Much love and respect

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `e.preventDefault()` is to mark the button as being of `type="button"` the default inside a `<form>` element is `type="submit"` which automatically submits the form/refreshes the page.

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.addHobby.bind(this)}>ADD Hobby</button>
```

Setting `type="button" indicates that the button is just there to trigger some JavaScript action, not to submit the form.